# How to get to know age of Azure Virtual machine through terraform code?

Tags: azure, terraform, cloud, virtual-machine

I was attempting to write a script to delete azure vms which are older than 5 days. Is there any way to get the age of a particular vm with terraform code?

I tried finding on the hashicorp docs but couldnt find anything.

Comment: You can use a `null_resource` to run a script : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a task to use terraform. you'd need to use something like az cli or powershell to do that. A code example:

```
$vms = Get-AzVM
$vms.where{
  $PSItem.TimeCreated -lt (get-date).adddays(-5)
} | Remove-AzVM
```

this is not tested, but should get you almost there